# Site .NET com alta performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, desempenho

Vou iniciar a construção de um site para compra de ingressos e a previsão de acesso a página principal é de 8000 usuários por minuto.

Obrigatoriamente usaremos C# .NET e MVC.

O banco de dados, padrão de projeto, ORM e *frameworks* estão em aberto e podem ser escolhidos.

Até o momento penso em fazer uma WebApi 2.0 com padrão Repository e Micro ORM Dapper, AngularJS e banco de dados SQL Server mas gostaria de conhecer algumas opiniões.

Qual a sugestão de vocês? Implementariam um sistema de filas ou para essa quantidade de usuários não é necessário?

Obs. Levem em conta um servidor de médio a baixo potencial.

Comment: O que seria um sistema de filas?

Comment: Similar a que alguns sites de compras fazem na black friday. A partir de um número X de acessos aparece uma mensagem: "Você é o número 10 da fila, aguarde".

Comment: Isto ocorre para navegar, para a pessoa fechar a compra, ou que? Eu estou imaginando porque precisam fazer isto. Eu já responderia de antemão que só tem um jeito de saber. Testar. Vai fazendo e vai fazendo testes de carga.

Comment: Concordo. E em relação a arquitetura, frameworks, banco etc, você utilizaria algo diferente? MongoDB por exemplo

Comment: Aí é muito específico, mas acho que não. Este site (ou melhor ainda o SO em inglês) tem um tráfico absurdamente maior (e acho que vocês estão sendo otimistas com esta ideia de 8k users/minute) e usa SQL Server e vários níveis de cache. Isto sim é importante. Veja se tem mais algum detalhe, vou por uma resposta que não é algo específico, mas acho que isto nem dá para responder, mas será alguma coisa pra não ficar só no comentário.

Comment: Agradeço sua ajuda bigown. A pergunta realmente é subjetiva, qualquer conselho ou sugestão é bem vindo. Não vou me preocupar com fila inicialmente, farei o site e os testes de carga e se isso apontar um problema, volto a pensar no sistema de filas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consolidando o que está nos comentários.

Qualquer decisão tem que passar por testes de carga e *stress* ou uso real em produção. Não adianta supor coisas. E vai ter que refazer estes testes conforme for adicionando funcionalidade.

De qualquer forma se não souber o que está fazendo vai ter problemas independente do sistema que crie e até do hardware que use.

Esse sistema de filas pra mim é algo esquisito. Eu acho que é barbeiragem, duvido do que ele seria necessário se soubesse o que está fazendo.

A rede Stack Exchange que você está usando agora [tem muito acesso e não tem problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/10m). Eles usam basicamente [a tecnologia que pretende usar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/140010). O MongoDB pode ser melhor que o SQL Server pro seu caso? Você sabe melhor que eu.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se deveria usar AngularJS, acho que há muito uso por moda, mas seria só minha opinião. Até acho que isto reduzirá os esforços necessários no servidor. Mas há outras implicações boas ou ruins.

Claro que em determinado momento a solução é adicionar hardware. Horizontal ou verticalmente. Não tem jeito. E sai absurdamente mais barato que implementar uma solução de software complexa demais para desenvolver ou suportar.

O erro maior que eu vejo nesta afirmação é especificar em qual hardware vai rodar. O hardware deve ser dimensionado de acordo com a necessidade, não ficar mudando o software para atender a limitação do hardware, até porque isto nem sempre é possível. Mesmo quando é, a opção é a pior possível.

Conforme vai tendo necessidade pode ir melhorando algumas coisas. Mas de início aprenderia muito sobre cache. Faça em vários níveis. Isto ajuda muito a ter escalabilidade e até lidar com alguns tipos de ataque.

Claro, o *design* da aplicação pode influenciar muito no desempenho. Não vou falar sobre isto porque não há detalhes que eu possa dizer algo adequado, mas eu vejo muito software ter problemas de desempenho porque foram mal projetados (nem estou falando de código mal escrito, que também gera problemas). Em determinado momento vai ter que pensar se quer uma funcionalidade. Tem coisas que fariam este site ser muito melhor do que é, mas ele não permite porque aumentaria muito o custo de processamento. Eles optaram pelo desempenho em detrimento da UX (ainda que o desempenho também seja um aspecto da UX). Tem muitos sites que fazem isto. Facebook e Google vivem tomando decisões assim. Mas lembre-se que você não é o Facebook.

Comment: Ótima resposta, tbm acho que não tem como supor o desempenho antes de desenvolver a aplicação, muito menos baseando-se na informação de um "Hardware Médio/Baixo". De qualquer forma, acredito que o stack proposto rodando no Azure, suportaria, com custo acessível, qualquer carga de trabalho.